# Adding background img if screen resolution width >1028

Tags: javascript, background, image, screen-resolution

**Hi guys,**

I'm fairly new to javascript. I have a pretty simple script I wrote to add a background image if the screen resolution width is bigger than 1028px.

Unfortunately, after trying this (on another computer, with 800x600 resolution), it doesn't work.

I'm not looking to stretch the image, just simply add it if the screen resolution width is bigger than or equal to 1024.

Here is the code:

```
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    document.write('<style type="text/css">div#container_header_body {background-image:url(\'');
    if (screen.width<1024)
    {
     document.write('none;');
    }
    else
    {
      document.write('images/mmmgirl.png');
    }
    document.write('\');</style>');
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

Can anybody give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much. I've already learned a LOT from this place.

*- - Andrew*

Comment: PS. `<!--` and `//-->` can safely be omitted, just like the `language` attribute. It seems that you're using an ancient JavaScript tuturial. A better place to get information is the Mozilla Developer's Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL9L2/):

```
var screenWidth = screen.width,
    container = document.getElementById('container_header_body');

console.log(screenWidth);

if (screenWidth > 1024) {
     container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://oddanimals.com/images/lime-cat.jpg)';
} else {
    container.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question, the same goes for *answers*.

Answer (score 2):

No need for JavaScript, just use a [CSS media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    background-image: url(images/mmmgirl.png);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Does it work for all browsers? If it does, I love this answer!

Comment: @GraceShao [All modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) support it. IE as of version 9.